# Cannot find the mpm configuration file in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I installed httpd with `yum install` on CentOS, and the version is `httpd-2.2.3-65.el5.centos.3`.

But I cannot find the `httpd-mpm.conf` file and the `apachectl` file.

The server runs fine but I don't know what mpm module is being used. How can I show and change the the mpm module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the current MPM:

```
$ /usr/sbin/httpd -V | grep "Server MPM"
Server MPM:     Prefork
```

To change, edit your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file.